# My laptop key is not working but doesn't seem jammed or stuck?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My right arrow key is not working, but it doesn't seem to be jammed. Still looks like all the other keys and presses normally... but nothing happens. I have an Acer Aspire laptop. I've tried gently pulling at the key but it doesn't look removable and I'm afraid to break it altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: See if you can find a manufacturers manual for your laptop (most have service guides available).  That *might* detail key removal.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull it quite far. Keyboard buttons are normally clicked in, so I don't see why yours wouldn't be. I've had a similar problem with a Fujitsu Siemens.

What happens when you press really hard?

Comment: Are you sure? When I pull I feel like I'm pulling at a sort of spring... it kind of stretches. Nothing happens when I press hard :-/ It's totally not working

Comment: Yes it's connected through some kind of spring. Look up your exact model and look how to change keyboard buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment I'll go ahead and give an answer.

Yes, some keyboards on laptops just pop off as described. However, several of the newer laptops with the the low profile keys are going to a scissor hinge arrangement which if you force, may or may not cause permanent damage to the key. I don't know whether your model utilizes this style.

To check you can lift up on the edge a key and peer in with some light shined in there. If it is of the scissor hinge type you will see something like this:

[image]

This is the style on my Acer Aspire One and my Macbook Pro. The technique to remove these usually includes lifting the key while pushing on the hinge mounting point. [This](http://youtu.be/TawSCmb08tM) is a demo video on YouTube. While it's for a MBP, the technique is similar.

If it is the old style (which you won't see the hinge) then it's usually safe to just pry them off.

Source: Personal experience...for what that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

First, your keyboard may simply be broken. It does happen, but before you have to consider replacement, you can try these basics to cleaning sticky keys:

1. Pop off the key using a small flat-head screwdriver (I have never seen keys that do not pop off, but if you are not sure, Google your computer model, keyboard, remove keys). If there are little rubber o-rings, also remove them and place them somewhere safe as they are easily lost.
2. Clean the areas underneath it with rubbing alcohol.
3. Replace the key.

Here are two links with additional instructions, which may help you further.

http://www.ehow.com/how_2107252_fix-sticking-laptop-keys.html

http://www.ehow.com/how_4797672_stuck-key-laptop-computer-keyboard.html